# How to tell height of a sprite after zrotation?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a sprite like this:

[image]

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "sprite.png")
print("sprite height: \(sprite.size.height)") //results to 150

sprite.zRotation = 90 * degreesToRadians //turns sprite 90 Degrees
```

Results to this:

[image]
However:

```
print("sprite height: \(sprite.size.height)") //results to 150
```

Sprite height is still 150 even though it takes far less space height-wise.

Is there a way to get the actual height of a sprite after zrotating it? I know I could easily work around this with in the example above but my real problem is that I have various sprites at various zrotations and I'm trying to make sure that all of them are fully visible on screen.

So basically I have a sprite (red bar), an anchor point at 0,0 (blue dot) and visible screen (black frame).

[image]

I zrotate the sprites to random angles using `arc4random_uniform` but some sprites end up not being completely visible on screen. Basically I would have to know the `height` of the green arrow or assign it as the `anchorPoint` after zrotation. Or perhaps there are other ways that I have not thought of. All help appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Try `sprite.frame.size.height`

Comment: @0x141E How can I then position the sprite within the viewable screen? The sprite.position is still relative to the "pre zrotation" state so sprite ends up in wrong position on screen even if I count its height by its frame.

Comment: @0x141E is it possible for example to reset the anchorpoint so that it would reflect the "zrotated" point of 0,0?

Comment: Rotating a sprite doesn't change its position regardless of the location of the `anchorPoint`. Also, changing the anchor point doesn't change the sprite's position. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @0x141E I refactored the question to better describe my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0x141E's comment works.

```
sprite.frame.size.height
```

results to correct outcome.